# Is it possible to use AWS::CloudFormation::Init and metadata in AWS::OpsWorks::Instance resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-opsworks

I want to create a stack by opsworks and I want to configure user data in my stack instances. I'm not going to need an auto scaling group, so is it possible to use metadata and AWS::CloudFormation::Init in an AWS::OpsWorks::Instance resource the way we do in AWS::EC2::Instance and launch configuration?

```
 "Resources": {
      "MyInstance": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
        "Metadata" : {
          "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
            "config" : {
              "packages" : {},
              "groups" : {},
              "users" : {},
              "sources" : {},
              "files" : {},
              "commands" : {},
              "services" : {}
            }
          }
        },
        "Properties": {
          [...]
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: Use Chef recipes and cookbooks to configure an `AWS::OpsWorks::Instance`, not `cfn-init`.

Internally, OpsWorks uses `cloud-init` to install the AWS OpsWorks Stacks agent on the instance (see [Using Custom AMIs: Startup Behavior](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workinginstances-custom-ami.html#workinginstances-custom-ami-work-startup)). Presumably for this reason, setting a custom user-data script is not supported on OpsWorks instances, so you can't run `cfn-init` on startup the same way you can on regular `AWS::EC2::Instance` resources.

For a workaround, you could [use a custom AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workinginstances-custom-ami.html#workinginstances-custom-ami-work-startup) for your instance and configure the AMI to invoke `cfn-init` on startup.

However, a workaround like that is strongly discouraged- you really shouldn't ever need to use `cfn-init` (or its corresponding `AWS::CloudFormation::Init` metadata) in an OpsWorks stack to begin with. `cfn-init` is entirely orthogonal to the much more robust Chef-based configuration management that OpsWorks provides, which is presumably the reason you're using OpsWorks in the first place. Take advantage of it! Use Chef recipes and cookbooks to configure your instance.

If you really need to use `cfn-init` and custom user-data (to support legacy code, for example), then I'd recommend sticking to standard EC2 instances until you can port your application logic over to custom Chef cookbooks.

Comment: The problem with this logic is that Chef relies on code checked into a repository. If you're doing custom recipes and need user data to configure your instance to access the repository you get a catch 22 problem.